# How to log to AWS Cloud Watch using server less yml and angular 8

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless, angular8, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

### Scenario:

I have a web application which has been created using angular8 and serverless yml, I want to log the error to AWS CloudWatch if any error occurred at the front end.

### What I have tried :

I am also using ngx-logger package for the same.

### The problem:

I don't want to share the key/secret in the web application to put logs to cloud watch using aws-sdk.
Front-end: Web-Application
Rest API: aws-api url (if I am to use it to put logs directly to CLoudWatch)
Is there any package available for this without having to expose aws credentials, which is important for security compliance reasons?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access AWS resources in the front-end, you have 2 choices:

1. Using AWS Cognito (AWS' authentication solution)
2. Using Signed Request

For the second choice, you need to create an API (maybe using lambda) and create a request signature and give it to your front-end. (you may need to use your own authentication function here)

In both choices, you need to associate an IAM role which has necessary permissions to write into your cloudwatch.